# Jquery ui tabs advanced issue on next and previous

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Kindly visit this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Kq66/

**What I want:** When user is viewing, if any of the 1st three tabs `tab 1`, `tab 2` or `tab 3` is active  the prev link will be hidden so that no one can get back, and when any of the last three tabs `tab 4`, `tab 5` or `tab 6` is active the next link will be hidden so that no one can go further. How can I get that? (dynamically if possible)

Here is the Jquery code I am using:

```
$(".wrapper #tab1,.wrapper #tab2").tabs({active: 0}).tabs({
        collapsible: false,
        hide: {
                effect: "slideUp",
                duration: 20
        },
        show: {
                effect: "slideDown",
                duration: 200
        }
});

var all = $('.wrapper .main').addClass("passiv");

var i = -1;

$('.wrapper .prev').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ctrlcontent( i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i );
});
$('.wrapper .next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ctrlcontent( i = ++i % all.length );
}).click();

function ctrlcontent(ele) {
        all.removeClass("active").addClass("passiv");
        all.eq(ele).removeClass("passiv").addClass("active");
}


$(function() {
        $( ".wrapper .inner" ).buttonset();
});
```

**N.B:** I am new to Jquery Ui, answer with details if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to only make 2 small changes to your existing code:

- First - disable the "cycle" function in the two .click() handlers
- Second - Add a condition in the ctrlcontent() function to show/hide the next/prev links

Click-Handlers look like this:

```
$('.wrapper .prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Remove this line, since this causes the "cycle" effect
    // ctrlcontent( i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i );

    // Use this logic:
    // When we are on first tab then do nothing, since there is no previous tab
    if (i == 0) {
        // Do not call ctrlcontent, since there is no previous tab
    } else {
        i -= 1;
        ctrlcontent(i);
    }
});

$('.wrapper .next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Also remove this line and add the condition below:
    //ctrlcontent( i = ++i % all.length );

    // When we are on the last tab then do nothing, since there is no next tab
    if (i == all.length-1) {
        // Do nothing, since there is no next tab
    } else {
        i += 1;
        ctrlcontent(i);
    }
}).click();
```

The ctrlcontent function will need a few conditions to decide which links to show:

```
function ctrlcontent(index_to_show) {
   all.removeClass("active").addClass("passiv");
   all.eq(index_to_show).removeClass("passiv").addClass("active");

    // now check if we need to show/hide the prev/next links
    if (index_to_show == 0) {
        // We are on first page, so hide the "prev"-link
        prev.hide();
    }

    if (index_to_show == all.length-1) {
        // We are on the last tab, so hide the "next"-link   
        next.hide();
    }

    if (index_to_show > 0) {
        // We are on a tab _after_ the first one, so there should be a "prev"-link
        prev.show();
    }

    if (index_to_show < all.length-1) {
        // We are a tab _before_ the last one, so we need the "next"-link
        next.show();
    }
}
```

Note: The above examples are not optimized. You can write them much shorter.

Another remark from me: You should rename the variable "i" to something like "current_tab", etc. It makes the code easier to read/debug.

---

Here is the same code in a shorter version:

```
$(".wrapper #tab1,.wrapper #tab2").tabs({active: 0}).tabs({
        collapsible: false,
        hide: {
                effect: "slideUp",
                duration: 20
        },
        show: {
                effect: "slideDown",
                duration: 200
        }
});

var all = $('.wrapper .main').addClass("passiv");
var prev = $('.wrapper .prev');
var next = $('.wrapper .next');
var tab_count = all.length-1;
var i = -1; // I suggest to call this "current", etc. "i" is no good ides...

prev.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   

    if (i != 0) {
        i -= 1;
        ctrlcontent(i);
    }
});

next.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (i < tab_count) {
        i += 1;
        ctrlcontent(i);
    }
}).trigger('click');

function ctrlcontent(index_to_show) {
   all.removeClass("active").addClass("passiv");
   all.eq(index_to_show).removeClass("passiv").addClass("active");

   if (index_to_show == 0) prev.hide();
   if (index_to_show == tab_count) next.hide();
   if (index_to_show > 0) prev.show();
   if (index_to_show < tab_count) next.show();
}


$(function() {
        $( ".wrapper .inner" ).buttonset();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do. Using jquery ui event you can get the index of the current tab like so.

```
var activeIdx = 0; /* probably starting off at the zero index */
```

When a tab is clicked in its click event set the above activeIdx. So in your init of the tabs themselves add a select event.

```
beforeActivate: function(event, ui){
    activeIdx = ui.index
}

if(activeIdx <= 2){
  // hide ur prev button or create a disabled class.
} else {
  // hide ur next btn or add disabled class.
}
```

So essentially all you are doing is checking that selected or active index of the tab regardless of what other events and anchors you have going and if it is less than or equal to you know you're on the first set of tabs. make sense?

EDIT: you can also set your tabs to a variable like:

```
var _tabs = $(".wrapper #tab1,.wrapper #tab2").tabs(); // omit above hide/show for brevity.
```

Then grab the index as such.

```
activeIdx = _tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
```

Comment: Notice that he's using jQuery UI 1.10.2. `select` was replaced in favor of `beforeActivate`[jQuery UI 1.10 upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#tabs)

Comment: @SirDerpington- It works same for previous versions of jquery Ui, I just use UI 1.10.2 for no other purposes.

Comment: @C.Hazelton- Can you edit my fiddle, and give me a working demo? It would be better for me to understand

Comment: @Shovon if someone doesn't do it in a few I will on a call at moment.